# Generalization of Cauchy's identity

Tags: co.combinatorics, schur-functions, generating-functions

Let $ s_{\lambda} $ be the Schur function associated to the partition $ \lambda $.
Cauchy's identity (as in Macdonald) states that

$$ 
\sum_{\lambda} s_{\lambda}(X)s_{\lambda}(Y) = \prod_{i,j}(1-x_iy_j)^{-1}
$$

where the sum is over all partitions.  There is a generalization appearing in a paper by Ishikawa and Tagawa [Schur Function Identities and Hook Length Posets](http://poisson.ms.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~mi/papers/fpsac07b.pdf) (Theorem 2.1(i)) which states that if $ X=(x_1,...,x_m) $ and $ Y=(y_1,...,y_m) $,

$$
\sum_{\lambda} w^{\lambda_m}s_{\lambda}(X)s_{\lambda}(Y) =
\frac{1-|X||Y|}{(1-w|X||Y|)\prod_{i,j=1}^m(1-x_iy_j)}
$$

where the sum is over partitions $ \lambda=(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_m) $ and $ |X|: = x_1x_2\cdots x_m $.

I am curious if there is a result along these lines which gives a closed form product expression for the generating function

$$
\sum_{\lambda} z_1^{\lambda_1}\cdots z_{m-1}^{\lambda_{m-1}}z_m^{\lambda_m}s_{\lambda}(X)s_{\lambda}(Y)
$$

where the sum is still over partitions $ \lambda=(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_m) $.
In particular, at least for now I care about such a generating function in the form

$$
\sum_{\lambda} w^{\lambda_{m-1}}z^{\lambda_m}s_{\lambda}(X)s_{\lambda}(Y)
$$

It is my understanding that such a result can likely be discovered via the RSK correspondence, but this is not really my field.  Thus before I delve into possibly slowly reinventing the wheel I thought I'd ask.

Comment: What is $w$? Even in the underlying paper, it is never introduced. Supposedly it is a weight between $0$ and $1$, with $w=1$ yielding Cauchy's identity. But $w=0$ yields nonsense. Is there simply a factor $w$ missing on the RHS?

Comment: @Wolfgang why does $w=0$ yield nonsense? It reduces to a generating function over partitions with $\lambda_m=0$.

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi Oh sure, I didn't realize that terms with $0^0=:1$ would survive on the LHS. And of course I guess it is tacitly assumed  as usual that $\lambda_1\ge\cdots\ge\lambda_m$,.