# Is there always a prime between $\beta z^\alpha$ and $\beta (z+1)^\alpha$ for $z$ large enough, and a fixed $\alpha < 2$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

I am interested if possible in $\beta = \frac{2}{3}, \alpha=\frac{3}{2}$ and $z$ is a positive integer or real number. My choice here is related to some progress I make in additive combinatorics (see my last answer to this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363055/goldbach-conjecture-and-other-problems-in-additive-combinatorics/)). It would make my life easier if this was true.

However, I can be less picky: all I really need it seems, is $\alpha < 2$. The closest $\alpha$ is to $2$, of course the more likely the answer to my question could be positive, but it also makes some arguments in my previous MO question less likely to work out. For $\beta$, you can pick up any positive value that would give a positive answer to my question.

Comment: Of course, the answer is "no" for $\alpha\leq 1$. For $\alpha>1$ this is conjecturally true, but not proven. This is a question about maximal prime gaps, specifically whether they are $O(p_n^{\alpha-1})$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Upper_bounds) for known results.

Comment: Indeed, it's not even known whether there's always a prime between consecutive squares, so the question here seems hopeless.

Comment: Correction from my previous comment: the exponent should be, I think, $\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha}$, not $\alpha-1$.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I will stop wasting my time trying to prove my problem. That was supposed to be the easiest of the two big challenges I am facing, and it turns out to be unproven yet.