# Given a positive integer $n$, some straight lines and lattice points such... Prove that the number of the lines is at least $n(n+3)$

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, algebraic-combinatorics

I was trying to get an answer on [MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3833778/given-a-positive-integer-n-some-straight-lines-and-lattice-points-such-pro) long ago and now I got it.

> Given a positive integer $n$ and some straight lines in the plane
> such that none of the lines passes through $(0,0)$, and such that every lattice point
> $(a,b)$, where $ 0\leq a,b\leq n$ are integers and $a+b>0$, is contained
> by at least $a+b+1$ of the lines. Prove that the number of the lines is at
> least $n(n+3)$.

**Solution:** Let us count the number of pairs $({\bf line},{\bf point})$ on two ways.

- Say we have $l$ lines and each can pass at most $n+1$ points. Say $k$ of them pass through $n+1$ points, then $k\leq 2n+1$. So all of them pass at most through $$k(n+1)+n(l-k) \leq (l+2)n+1$$ points, so we have at most $(l+2)n+1$ pairs $({\bf line},{\bf point})$.
- On the other hand all points pass at least thorugh $$\sum_{a=0}^n\sum_{b=0}^n (a+b+1)-1 = n^3+3n^2+3n  $$ lines, so we have at list that many pairs $({\bf line},{\bf point})$.
- So we have $$n^3+3n^2+3n\leq (l+2)n+1\implies l\geq n(n+3)$$
  and thus a conclusion.

Is there a polynomial method aproach to this problem? (Like defining some polynomials which wanish on some set of points...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With polynomial method you may prove the same bound even if the lines are allowed to coincide. Then it is sharp:  consider the vertical and horizontal lines $x=a$ and $y=a$ taken $a+1$ times for $a=1,2,\ldots,n$. Also it works over any field (and with points $(\alpha_i,\beta_j)$ on the place of $(i,j)$, where $\{\alpha_0,\ldots,\alpha_n\}$ and $\{\beta_0,\ldots,\beta_n\}$ are arbitrary subsets of the field.)

For the proof, we adapt the standard Alon -- Furedi trick for the multisets. Namely, we use the multisets analogue of [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/214930/4312) formula.

If $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ is a multiset, denote by $n(a)$ the multiplicity of the element $a$ in $A$. If $f(x)\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ is a polynomial, we say ``the values of $f$ on $A$'' for the sequence of numbers $f^{(i)}(a)$, where $a\in A$ and $0\leqslant i\leqslant n(a)-1$. It is well known that if $\deg f\leqslant |A|-1$, $f$ is uniquely determined by its values on $A$ (Hermite interpolation). In particular, the coefficient $[x^{|A|-1}] f(x)$ may be written in the form $\Phi_A(f)$, where $\Phi_A$ is a linear combination of the values of $f$ on $A$.

**Remark.** Whenever $n(a)=1$, the value $f(a)$ participates in $\Phi_A$ non-trivially. This follows from considering the sample polynomial $f(x):=\prod_{b\in A\setminus a} (x-b)^{n(b)}$.

Now if we have two multisets $A,B\subset \mathbb{R}$ and the polynomial $f(x,y)$ such that $\deg f\leqslant |A|+|B|-2$, we may write the formula $$\left[x^{|A|-1}y^{|B|-1}\right]f=\left(\Phi_A\otimes \Phi_B\right) f(x,y).\quad\quad\quad(1)$$
Here we identify the space of polynomials in $(x,y)$ with the tensor product of polynomials in $x$ and polynomials in $y$. So, (1) allows to reconstruct the coefficient of $x^{|A|-1}y^{|B|-1}$ in the polynomial $f$ via the values $((\partial/\partial x)^i (\partial/\partial y)^j f)(a,b)$, $a\in A$, $b\in B$,
$i$, $j$ are less then corresponding multiplicities of $a$ in $A$ and $b$ in $B$. The coefficient of such guy is a product of corresponding coefficients for 1-dimensional reconstruction formulae.

Once stated, (1) is easy to prove: by linearity, we may think that $f(x,y)=x^k y^l$, $k+l\leqslant |A|+|B|-2$. Then RHS of (1) reads as $\Phi_A(x^k) \Phi_B(y^l)$. If both $k\leqslant |A|-1$, $l\leqslant |B|-1$, we may use the 1-dimensional formulae $\Phi_A(x^k)=[x^{|A|-1}]x^k$, $\Phi_B(y^l)=[y^{|B|-1}]y^l$. If, say, $k\geqslant |A|$, the 1-dimensional formula is no longer valid for $x^k$, but we have $l<|B|-1$, and for $y^l$ the formula $\Phi_B(y^l)=[y^{|B|-1}]y^l$ is valid and gives 0. Cause of this 0, it does not really matter what is the value $\Phi_A(x^k)$.

Well, now back to the problem. Assume that we have less than $n(n+3)$ lines. Take the product of their equations, it is a polynomial $f(x,y)$ of degree less than $n(n+3)$. Consider the multisets $A=B=\{0,1,1,2,2,2,\ldots,n,\ldots,n\}$, $|A|=n(n+3)/2+1$. We have $\deg f<|A|+|B|-2$, thus $[x^{|A|-1}y^{|B|-1}]f=0$. But applying (1) we see that there is unique non-zero term in RHS, which corresponds to $f(0,0)$: all other terms have the form $((\partial/\partial x)^i (\partial/\partial y)^j f)(a,b)$, $(a,b)\ne (0,0)$, $i\leqslant a,j\leqslant b$, they do vanish because of the multiplicity condition. The term $f(0,0)$ goes with non-zero coefficient due to Remark. A contradiction.

You may read more about this multisets formula in [G. Károlyi, Z.-L. Nagy, F. V. Petrov, V. Volkov. A new approach to constant term identities and Selberg-type integrals. Adv. Math. 277 (2015), 252-282], earlier the tensor product view appeared in [U. Schauz. Algebraically solvable problems: describing polynomials as equivalent to explicit solutions. Electron. J. Combin. 15 (2008) #R10, 35 p.]

---

When the lines are all distinct, this seems to be too weak bound, let me prove $\Omega(n^{5/2})$.

If a point is covered by a line, draw a flower at this place. The number of flowers should be at least $cn^3$ for some $c>0$. On the other hand, denote by $r_k$ the number of lines containing at least $k$ points. The vector between consecutive lattice points on such line may be chosen by $O(n^2/k^2)$ ways, the line should pass through a point which may be chosen by $O(n^2)$ ways, and each such line is counted at least $k$ times, totally we get $r_k\leqslant С n^4/k^3$ for certain $C$. Choose large $M$ and consider only $k\geqslant M\sqrt{n}$. We get $\sum_{k\geqslant M\sqrt{n}} r_k\leqslant Cn^4/(M^2n)=(C/M^2)n^3<cn^3/2$ if $M$ is large enough. This means that if label only $\max(s,[M\sqrt{n}])$ flowers corresponding to each line containing exactly $s$ points, the total number $\sum_{k> M\sqrt{n}} r_k$ of not-labelled flowers is at most $cn^3/2$. All other $cn^3/2$ flowers are labelled, and each line contains at most $M\sqrt{n}$ labelled flowers. Thus the number of lines is not less then $\frac{c}{2M} n^{5/2}$.

Comment: OK, but can you help me with polynomial method for original problem?

Comment: I hope I can, but I find it quite a strange thing to think about. I may think about the version when the lines may coincide, then it looks similar to the Alon-Furedi with multiplicities.

Comment: @Aqua sorry, I was thinking for couple of days that $a+b+1=1$ for $a=0,b=1$. The bound is sharp for not necessarily distinct lines, and this may be proved using polynomials (I doubt about the proof without them), see the updated answer.

Comment: Great, many thanks Fedor!

Comment: a naive problem, is $\Omega\left(n^{5 / 2}\right)$ sharp when the lines are all distinct?

Comment: @katago I think so. For each point $(a,b)\ne (0,0)$ consider all integer vectors $u$ such that (i) $\|u\|<1000\sqrt{n}$; (ii) the line $\ell_u:=(a,b)+\mathbb{R}\cdot u$ does not pass through $(0,0)$; (iii) $\ell_u$ contains at least $\sqrt{n}/10000$ points on our grid. Totally the number of lines through each point is at least $2n+1$ and $O(n)$. Each line is counted at least $\sqrt{n}/10000$ times, thus we get $O(n^{5/2})$ distinct lines.

Comment: @Fedor Petrov, by analytic number theory argument I can prove if lines are distinct then we need at least $O(\frac{n^3}{(\ln n)^2})$ number of lines, and it seems even this can be majorly improved.

Comment: @Fedor Petrov, the previous argument seems can not prove $O\left(n^{5 / 2}\right)$ is optimal because the number of line such that generated by $\ell_{u}:=(a, b)+\mathbb{R} \cdot u, \|u\|<1000 \sqrt{n}$ is much less than $n^2$ by some number theory argument, I write it below as an answer, hope there is no majar mistake.

Comment: @katago hm, for each $(a,b)$ we have roughly $n$ such lines (since there are roughly $n$ admissible primitive vectors $u$), totally roughly $n^3$ lines. But each line is counted at least $\sqrt{n}$ times, so the real number of lines is at most $n^{5/2}$. What's wrong here?

Comment: @Fedor Petrov, I am not very sure already, but what is the roughly $n$ admissible primitive vectors $u$, you mean satisfied the condition (i),(ii),(iii) mention in your previous comment? In my argument(if it is true), it can derive there are not so many admissible primitive vectors $u$.

Comment: Yes your argument is totally true, and there is an error when I estimate $\#\left\{l \mid l \cap L=\frac{n}{k}\right\}$, it can be fixed(not totally wrong), it seems like then the result is $O\left(n^{\frac{5}{2}} /(\ln n)^{2}\right)$, I am not sure now and I will check it later.

Comment: @Fedor Petrov, thanks for point out, in fact, my argument can and only can give the bound $O\left(n^{\frac{5}{2}} /(\ln n)^{2}\right)$, I believe.

Comment: @katago I think, for each $(a,b)$ all primitive vectors in one of four quadrants are admissible.

Comment: @Fedor Petrov, I think it is the full $O(N)$, we are counting $(p,q),\max{p,q}\leq N, gcd(p,q)=1$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117635/discussion-between-fedor-petrov-and-katago).

Answer (score 5):

You can get a better bound with a simpler proof.
Consider only the $n+1$ points for which $b=n$.
There is at most one line that goes through at least two of these points.
Thus any point $(a,n)$ has at least $a+n+1-1=a+n$ lines that go through only it from among these points.
So just through these points we have at least
$$1+\sum_{a=0}^n (a+n)=1+n+(n+1)+...+(2n)=\frac{3n(n+1)}2+1$$
lines.

Answer (score 0):

When the lines are all distinct it seems to be too weak bound as mentioned previously by Fedor Petrov.

let me prove for $n$ suffice large, the number of distinct lines we need to fill
the lattice $L$, i.e. s.t. $\forall 0\leqslant a,b\leqslant n, 1<a+b$,
$(a,b)$ is contained in at least $a+b+1$ of lines is $\Omega\left(n^{5/2} /(\ln n)^{2}\right)$. **This is weaker than Fedor Petrov's result, and it is a prove without involve polynomial method.**

the main argument is a mix of rearrangement inequality and mean value estimate for divisor function $d(n)=\sum_{d|n} 1$.

let $L=\{(a, b) \mid 0\leqslant  a, b \leqslant n, a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ be the lattice. $\#A$ is the number of elements in $A$.

> Remark: $L$ is not the lattice in the normal definition of mathematics, but let us call it lattice because it is very visualizable.

---

First let us estimate
$$\quad \#\{l \mid l \cap L=\frac{n}{k}\}\quad \quad (*)$$

$l$ runc in all the line in plane $\mathbb R^2$, and here the mean of $l \cap L=\frac{n}{k}$ is after some translation $T$ in translation group, $\# T(l)\cap L=\frac{n}{k}+o(n)$

In fact,
$$
\#\left\{l \mid l \cap L = \frac{n}{k}\right\} = 4\left(\sum_{d_1 d_2=k} d_{1} d_{2}\right)n\leqslant 4d(k)kn\quad\quad (**)  
$$

---

$(**)$ is wrong and it should be** $
\#\left\{l \mid l \cap L = \frac{n}{k}\right\} = \frac{4\left(\sum_{d_1 d_2=k} d_{1} d_{2}\right)n}{n/k}=4d(k)k^2n $, I will fix the following argument use this later.

---

and
$$\#\left\{l \mid l \cap L = \frac{n}{k}\right\}=O(d(k)kn)$$

> Remark:
> $4$ is the number of elements of the unity group $\{1,-1,i,-i\}$

---

Now. if $\bigcup_{i \in I} I_{i}$ fill the lattice $L$ s.t. $\forall a+b>0$
$(a,b)\subset \mathbb Z^2$ is contained in at least $a+b+1$ of lines.

Then
$$
\sum_{i \in I} \# l_{i} \geqslant n^{3}+3 n^{2}+3 n\geqslant n^{3}
$$

And by **rearrangement inequality**,

$$
\sum_{i \in I}\# l_{i}\leqslant\sum_{s=1}^{M} \sum_{l_i,  \# l_{i} = \frac{n}{s}} \# l_{i}=\sum_{s=1}^{M} \frac{n}{s} \cdot \#\left\{l \mid \# l\cap L = \frac{n}{s}\right\}.
$$

Where $\sum_{s=1}^{M-1} \{l_i|\# l_{i}=\frac{n}{s}\}\leq \# I \leq \sum_{s=1}^M \{l_i|\# l_{i}=\frac{n}{s}\}$ and by $(**)$ we know,

$$
\sum_{s=1}^{M} \frac{n}{s} \cdot \#\left\{l \mid \# l \cap L=\frac{n}{s}\right\}
\leqslant \sum_{s=1}^{M} \frac{n}{s}\cdot 4d(s)sn=\sum_{s=1}^{M}4d(s)n^2$$

So
$$\sum_{s=1}^{M} 4 d(s) n^{2} \geqslant n^{3}, \ so, \sum_{s=1}^{M} d(s)  \geqslant n$$

---

From the Fourier series of the Eisenstein series and the invariants of the Weierstrass elliptic functions, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function), we know,

$$\sigma_{k}(n)=\zeta(k+1) n^{k} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{c_{m}(n)}{m^{k+1}}$$
in particular we know,

$$d(n)=\sigma_{0}(n)=\zeta(1) \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{c_{m}(n)}{m}$$

so $\sum_{n<x}d(x)\sim x\ln x$, so for $n$ suffice large and $\epsilon>0$, $\# I\geqslant \sum_{s=1}^{\frac{n}{\ln n}}4d(s)sn$ so $\# I= $\Omega\left(n^{5/2} /(\ln n)^{2}\right)$$.

> Remark
> we can direct prove this,
> \begin{aligned}
> \sum_{n\leqslant x} d(n) &\left.=\sum_{n \leqslant x}\sum_{d|n}1\right. \
> &=\sum_{d \leqslant x} \sum_{n \leqslant x, d|n} 1 \
> &=\sum_{d \leqslant x}\left[\frac{x}{d}\right] \
> &=\sum_{d \leqslant x}\left(\frac{x}{d}+o(1)\right) \
> &=x \log x+O(x)
> \end{aligned}

---

Of course, there has some space to improve further, it seems very unlikely there is no cancellation when the distribution of $l$ in $I$ near the equal condition of rearrangement inequality because here I only use the $L_1$ norm of $L$
, but do not consider the shape of the function induce by lattice $L$, i.e. s.t. $\forall 0\leqslant a,b\leqslant n, 1<a+b$,
$(a,b)$ is contained in at least $a+b+1$ of lines.

and a question is, is this method can generalize to finite field case? If it can it will be very interesting, I try to solve the finite field toy problem first and then use Fourier analysis on $(\mathbb Z/{p \mathbb Z})^2$ then find in the frequency space the problem is almost the same as the physics space and there is something look like to be very difficult this way I can not solve.

Let me give a picture to explain $(**)$
[image]