# De Bruijn's sequence is odd iff $n=2^m-1$: Part I

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics

Among the families of sequences studied by Nicolaas de Bruijn (*Asymptotic Methods in Analysis*, 1958), let's focus on the (modified)
$$\hat{S}(4,n)=\frac1{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}(-1)^{n+k}\binom{2n}k^4.$$
An all-familiar fact states: *the Catalan number $C_n=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}n$ is odd iff $n=2^m-1$*. In the same tradition, I ask:

> **QUESTION.** Is this true? $\hat{S}(4,n)$ is odd iff $n=2^m-1$ for some $m\in\mathbb{Z_{\geq0}}$.

**POSTSCRIPT.** This question has been extended to my [other MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383327/de-bruijns-sequence-is-odd-iff-n-2m%e2%88%921-part-ii).

Comment: for what it worth, $(-1)^n(n+1)\hat{S}(4,n)$ is a constant term of $(1+b/a)^{2n}(1+c/b)^{2n}(1+d/c)^{2n}(1-a/d)^{2n}$

Comment: As an aside, in Dutch, all particles (like 'de') in a surname are capitalised unless a given name or initial precedes it. So: "Nicolaas de Bruijn" but "De Bruijn sequence".

Comment: @JulesLamers: I learned something. Thanks.

Comment: @JulesLamers it's interesting, but should such rules be extrapolated from Dutch to other languages? I am not sure, in Russian I would still write "последовательность де Брёйна".

Comment: @FedorPetrov At the start of a sentence, or like here in a title, certainly (that is even true for German names, like "von Neumann", where the article remains lower case otherwise). Elsewhere in a sentence it's less clear, though English seems to tend to follow the Dutch rule: see https://english.stackexchange.com/a/185889 and e.g. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincent_van_Gogh

Comment: I think the body of this question and of the other question you have asked on De Bruijn sequences should contain links to each other.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: this is done now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's true. This follows easily from the formula
$$
\hat{S}(4,n)=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}n\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{2n+k}k^2\binom{2n}{n+k}.\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(*)
$$

First of all, I prove your parity claim using $(*)$, and next prove $(*)$.
If $n+1$ is not a power of 2, then $C_n=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}n$ is even and so is RHS of $(*)$. If $n=2^m-1$, then $C_n$ is odd, the summand with $k=1$ in RHS of $(*)$ is odd and other summands are even: $\binom{2n+k}k=\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{k(k-1)}\binom{2n+k}{k-2}$ is even for $k=2,3,\ldots,n$ since $k(k-1)$ is not divisible by $2^{m+1}=2n+2$.

Now the proof of $(*)$. For $C:=(-1)^n (n+1)\hat{S}(4,n)$ we have
$$C=[x^{2n}y^{2n}z^{2n}t^{2n}](x-y)^{2n}(y-z)^{2n}(z-t)^{2n}(x+t)^{2n}=[x^{2n}y^{2n}z^{2n}t^{2n}]F,$$
where $$F=\prod_{j=-(n-1)}^{n}(x-y-j)(z-y-j)(z-t-j)(x+t-2n-j).$$
Denote $A=\{0,1,\ldots,2n\}$ and express the coefficient $[x^{2n}y^{2n}z^{2n}t^{2n}]F$ via the values of $F$ on $A^4$ using [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/214930/4312) formula.

Look how $F(x,y,z,t)\ne 0$ may be possible when $x,y,z,t\in A$. We must have $|x-y|\geqslant n, |y-z|\geqslant n, |z-t|\geqslant n$ and $x-y\ne n$, $z-y\ne n$, $z-t\ne n$. If $y$ lies between $x$ and $z$, the conditions $|x-y|\geqslant n, |z-y|\geqslant n$ yield $y=n$, $\{x,z\}=\{0,n\}$, but then either $x-y$ or $z-y$ equals $n$; a contradiction. Analogously if $z$ lies between $y$ and $t$. Thus $x-y,z-y,z-t$ have equal sign. If they are positive, we get $2n\geqslant x\geqslant y+n+1\geqslant n+1$ and
$n-1\geqslant z-n-1\geqslant t\geqslant 0$, thus $x+t\in [n+1,3n-1]$ and therefore $F(x,y,z,t)=0$; a contradiction. So we must have $n\geqslant y-n\geqslant x\geqslant 0$,  $2n\geqslant t\geqslant z+n\geqslant n$ and $x+t\in [n,3n]$. Since $F(x,y,z,t)\ne 0$, we conclude that $x+t=n$, $x=0$, $t=n$, thus $z=0$ and $y\in [n,2n]$. Then the cited formula allows to rewrite $C$ as a sum over $y$ which simplifies as $(*)$.

Comment: Interestingly, a very similar identity has recently appeared on the arXiv: identity (B) in the proof of Theorem 1 in [Nikolai Beluhov, *One Curious Identity Counting Graceful Labelings*, arXiv:2102.00412v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.00412v1). Any connection?

Answer (score 5):

I just wished to suggest an alternative (mechanical) proof whose details can be provided (using the WZ-method) for the identity
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}(-1)^{n+k}\binom{2n}k^4=\binom{2n}n\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{2n+k}k^2\binom{2n}{n+k}.\qquad \qquad (*)$$
The idea is: verify that both sides of $(*)$ satisfy the 2nd-order recurrence
\begin{align*}
A(n)a(n+2)- B(b)a(n+1) +C(n)a(n)=0 \end{align*}
with initial conditions $a(0)=1$ and $a(1)=14$; where
\begin{align*}
A(n)&=(2n + 3)(48n^2 + 66n + 23)(n + 2)^3 \\
B(n)&=13056n^6+ 96288n^5+ 289600n^4+ 453428n^3 + 388698n^2 + 172598n+31030 \\
C(n)&=4(n + 1)(48n^2 + 162n + 137)(2n + 1)^3. \end{align*}

Comment: I was always interested: is there an automatic way to *find* such an identity?

Comment: The story is: you can prove A=B, if you know both. But, knowing A alone does not offer (mechanically) what B is. Of course, on many occasions, there could be more than one such B. Is that what you ask?

Comment: Yes, but possibly under certain pattern of possible forms for B there is an algorithm which finds whether the identity with some B in this patter exists? Say, is there an algorithm to decide whether a certain binomial sum is a finite ratio of products of factorials of expressions $a_in+b_i$?