# A rather curious identity on sums over triple binomial terms

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, combinatorial-identities

While exploring the Baxter sequences from [my earlier MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412324/closed-formula-for-1-baxter-sequences), I obtained a rather curious identity (not listed on OEIS either). I usually try to employ the Wilf-Zeilberger (WZ) algorithm to justify such claims. To my surprise, WZ offers **two different** recurrences for each side of this identity.

So, I would like to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Is there a conceptual or **combinatorial reason** for the below equality?
> $$\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n+1}k\binom{n+1}{k+1}\binom{n+1}{k+2}
> =\frac2{n+2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n+1}k\binom{n-1}k\binom{n+2}{k+2}.$$

**Remark 1.** Of course, one gets an alternative formulation for the Baxer sequences themselves:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\binom{n+1}k\binom{n+1}{k+1}\binom{n+1}{k+2}}{\binom{n+1}1\binom{n+1}2}
=2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\binom{n+1}k\binom{n-1}k\binom{n+2}{k+2}}{\binom{n+1}1\binom{n+2}2}.$$

**Remark 2.** Yet, here is a restatement to help with combinatorial argument:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n+1}k\binom{n+1}{k+1}\binom{n+1}{k+2}
=2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n+1}k\binom{n}k\binom{n+1}{k+2}.$$

Comment: This is now OEIS sequence [A350265](https://oeis.org/A350265).

Comment: @PeterLuschny: thank you!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just playing around with it: The RHS multiplied by $n$ is the same as

$$2 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n+1}{k} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n+1}{k+2}.$$

Subtracting this from $n$ times the LHS gives

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n+1}{k} \binom{n+1}{k+2} \left( \binom{n}{k+1} - \binom{n}{k} \right).$$

Now you check that replacing $k$ with $n-1-k$ changes the sign of the summand, so the sum is zero.

Answer (score 11):

The combinatorial identity
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n+1}{k} \binom{n+1}{k+1} \binom{n+1}{k+2} =
2 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n+1}{k} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n+1}{k+2}
$$
has a simple combinatorial proof.

The left-hand side counts all triples $A,B,C \subseteq [n+1]$ whose sizes are $k,k+1,k+2$ for some $k$. These come in two types:

- $n+1 \in B$. The triple $A,B\setminus\{n+1\},C$ has sizes $k,k,k+2$, and the middle set is a subset of $[n]$.
- $n+1 \notin B$. The triple $\overline{C},\overline{B}\setminus\{n+1\},\overline{A}$ has sizes $\bar{k},\bar{k},\bar{k}+2$, where $\bar{k}=n-1-k$, and the middle set is a subset of $[n]$.

The triples of each type are counted by the sum on the right-hand side.

Comment: This is essentially the same proof as Sean Eberhard's.